# How to bind to asp.net control?

Tags: sql, asp.net

```
 <%--Link database to dropdownlist--%>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sdsDropDownListLocation"
    ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:2020LJCDT %>"
    SelectCommand="Select Location.LocationID AS LocationID, Location AS Location
                     FROM Location
                     LEFT JOIN Fact ON Fact.LocationID = Location.LocationID
                    Where Fact.Fact IS NULL">

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have created this SQL call and I want to bind this to a drop-down list? I would I go about doing that? I know this would be kinda the syntax below but what would go in the empty " "?

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlLocation" DataSourceID="sdsDropDownListLocation" DataTextField=" " DataValueField=" " SelectedValue='<%# Bind(" ") %>' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Selected Value in this case. You only need to fill  DataTextField="Location" and  DataValueField="LocationID". I have created a small sample for you using the Northwind Database for further clarification. I even included a validation in case you need it.

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CategoryID], [CategoryName], [Description] FROM [Categories]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CategoryName" DataValueField="CategoryID" AppendDataBoundItems="true"   >
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select Category" Value="-1"> </asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" InitialValue="-1" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Okay that works for me. Would you know how to bind that data to a database when a save button is clicked?

Comment: I have an EditItemTemplate and I have the  SelectedValue='<%# Bind("LocationID") %>' removed. Must declare the scalar variable "@LocationID". How would I get this to work with the code you provided?

Comment: please elaborate more. I dont understand

Comment: Nvm, I figured out an alternative way.